# Run a Spark SQL query on Databricks from .Net UI

Tags: .net, azure, apache-spark-sql, odbc, databricks

I want my users to run the Spark SQL queries in UI and see the result set of the query.

Internally .Net Rest API will pass the query from UI to Databricks cluster or notebook or odbc to run the query. And resultset should show to the end user .

My backend platform is databricks .

Please suggest how to achieve this with some code/code links. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Databricks' ODBC integration](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html) with `System.Data.Odbc` package in .Net - have you tried it?

Comment: Hey Alex ,I am trying that way as well. But just to test the connection Simba Spark ODBC driver DSN set up is not working.     I have installed odbc driver .Can you please suggest me to write the .net code  which connects to data bricks through odbc drivers . I have tried but getting some data source errors. Thanks !

Comment: I don’t have windows at hand, may try tomorrow on Mac... can you provide more information on your environment?

Comment: Sure ,I have tried connecting SImba odbc driver from windows and was able to connect..but from .net i'm unable to connect..

Comment: For this we need install ODBC drivers .So If i want to host my application in AZURE PAAS how do i over come this ODBC drivers issue?

Comment: for FaaS you need to be careful - Spark queries could be long, and your code could timeout.  One possible case could be that you have a notebook that will execute your query, and write results to some location on ADLS, or something like. And your Azure Function will trigger execution of the notebook as a job

Comment: In order to use this ODBC integration, I need to download the driver, right? Is there some other approach where I wouldn't need to download the driver? If no, let's say that I made it work with ODBC driver. When the times for deployment of my web app comes, would I need to somehow deploy this driver? @AlexOtt

Comment: yes, you will need to install this driver as part of deployment. Unfortunately I can't say much about webapp deployment on Azure